# Fastest way to read IDbConnection.Command data

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

Right now I'm using

```
OleDbDataAdapter objDataReader = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objDataReader.SelectCommand = myCommand;
objDataReader.Fill(myDataTable);
```

But I feel the DataTable object is a massive bloated object, I'd like to know if there's a way I can make my own object to send to data reader, or use a lighter one?

Comment: Not really an answer, but might be worth pointing out that tHe methods are not really sent along with every object.

Comment: There's only one reason a DataTable ever gets bloated: stuffing it with thousands of query results.  That's not a DT problem, that's a query problem.

Comment: Well given that DT has an object to identify each column, which can have many properties, like autoincrement, and datatable even can have primary keys and such, it's way bigger than just a plain object with properties from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I feel the DataTable object is a massive bloated object, I'd like
>   to know if there's a way I can make my own object to send to data
>   reader, or use a lighter one?

You call the **DataTable**'s [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx) method to load the data into it using a `IDataReader`. You said it the other way around, which is not true.

As far as the DataReader is concerned, this is in fact very fast. If you don't like using a DataTable, you can look at other alternatives such as Entity Framework or simply hydrating your own custom business objects by iterating through the DataReder as so:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   //Hydrate your objects here
}
```